# Go Telegram Bot API upload photo from local file

Tags: go, telegram, telegram-bot

I work with telegram using github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api
Later I uploaded photos using external links:
Simplified code is like this:

```
url := `http://path-to-image/img.jpg`
msg := tgbotapi.NewPhotoUpload(groupID, nil)
msg.FileID = url
msg.Caption = "New photo"
bot.Send(msg)
```

But now, my photos are available only in the closed local network. Links like http://example.loc/img.jpg obviously do not work. So, I download a file and then try to upload it from disk or from memory. There are lots of examples here https://github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api/blob/master/bot_test.go
But no one works. I tried all the examples and even more, but I always get various errors:

- Bad Request: there is no photo in the request
- Bad Request: host is invalid
- Bad Request: URL host is empty
- Bad Request: unsupported URL protocol

And so on.

Does anybody know how to upload photo from disk or from memory (even better). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to upload a picture from local disk is to read the file, then passing the byte array to a [FileBytes](https://github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api/blob/54104a08f947e08c460c45d195076e48e61f0a26/configs.go#L1020), wrap it with a [Chattable](https://github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api/blob/54104a08f947e08c460c45d195076e48e61f0a26/configs.go#L52) like [PhotoConfig](https://github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api/blob/54104a08f947e08c460c45d195076e48e61f0a26/configs.go#L257) and send it through `bot.send`:

```
photoBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/your/local/path/to/picture.png")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
photoFileBytes := tgbotapi.FileBytes{
    Name:  "picture",
    Bytes: photoBytes,
}
chatID := 12345678
message, err := bot.Send(tgbotapi.NewPhotoUpload(int64(chatID), photoFileBytes))
```

Here `tgbotapi.NewPhotoUpload()` creates a PhotoConfig for us.

Answer (score 0):

```
bot, err := tgbotapi.NewBotAPI(telegram_bot_token)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

```
file, _ := os.Open("image.jpg")
reader := tgbotapi.FileReader{Name: "image.jpg", Reader: file}

photo := tgbotapi.NewPhoto(telegram_group_id, reader)
photo.Caption = "test caption"

_, err = bot.Send(photo)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```